# USB C GaN charger with C8 input?

Tags: usb-c

While there is a decent amount of multiport chargers (often marketed as "desktop") chargers, it's really, really hard to find small and lightweight chargers with a C8 coupler (commonly called "figure 8"). Let's limit the question to GaN chargers for weight reasons and to chargers without legacy ports because that's just a waste now. The Satechi 165W is one such, it's a bit on the heavier side though.

Apple released their 70W GaN charger in 2023 summer and two more such chargers were launched Q4 2023 (the Belkin INC016ttBK got listed on Amazon in November 2023, the [Phihong AQ60W-59FKKA-R](https://www.phihong.com/press-release/phihong-releases-ultra-compact-60w-usb-c-pd3-0-smart-charger-utilizing-gan-technology) press release is from December 2023) I think it's a good time to gather our knowledge of these chargers. Here's the Phihong:

[image: Phihong AQ60W-59FKKA-R]

The [Belkin INC016ttBK](https://www.belkin.com/usb-c-core-gan-power-adapter-100w/P-INC016.html) is very similar to the Rocstor [45W](https://rocstor.com/product/45w-smart-usb-c-slim-power-adapter-6-fixed-usb-c-cable/) / [65W](https://rocstor.com/product/65w-smart-usb-c-slim-power-adapter-6-fixed-usb-c-cable/) / [100W](https://rocstor.com/product/100w-smart-usb-c-slim-power-adapter-6-fixed-usb-c-cable/) "Slim" charger series but they have fixed USB C cables which makes them less ideal, however they are thinner which is nice:

[image: Rocstor 65W]

A non-GaN charger would be the SLE60SPD96N01 however 185g for just 60W is really heavy (65W GaN chargers can weigh [less than half](https://www.transphormusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/ChargingHeadNetwork_HelpersLab65WGaNCharger.pdf)), I am inserting it for illustration:

[image: SLE60SPD96N01]

So I am looking for any GaN chargers with a C8 power coupler and USB C port/ports only -- not C cables, port(s). From all the above, the Apple 70W and the Phihong would be an answer to this. More would be great. And if we continue with looking for slimmer chargers, there's nothing: only the fixed USB C cable chargers above are slimmer than 1".

Oh and obviously only chargers with UL/ETL/TUV certification please. That should go without saying but, alas.

Comment: Kinda stupid, but what about Apple's USB-C chargers? They're not GaN (which is admittedly unfortunate) and are definitely overpriced, but all the high-wattage ones use normal C8 connectors, and come with the added benefit of having cute travel adapters.

Comment: Of course. The 70W is GaN even, their second after the 140W which even with being GaN is too big. I should've included the 70W in the collection, I will edit the question.

Comment: Would the 70W be slim enough to suffice as an answer?

Comment: Nah, it's even thicker than the Phihong.

Comment: Nice find! I have two problems. One is subjective: I mentioned in passing the Satechi 165W with the caveat "it's a bit on the heavier side" it's 340g, the one you found is 303.5g. The other is objective: I do not see any electrical safety certificates mentioned but that doesn't mean it doesn't have one -- I can't find any photos of the back to verify. There's also the Hyperjuice 245W (582 g) which based on this [image](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/hyper3-1440x810.jpg) also lacks such certifications. (The Satechi has an ETL cert, Phihong and Belkin has UL.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Satechi 145W USB-C 4-Port GaN Travel Charger](https://satechi.net/products/145w-usb-c-4-port-gan-travel-charger/Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80MDc0ODI2MzM0MjE2OA==?queryID=d336b74c7a2b110dad7e304137a542b7)

[image]

I ended up being unexpectedly in the market for a new USB-C charger with similar requirements:

- Support for 140W PD
- *Wall-wart form factor* with swappable C8 inputs
- USB-C only, with multiple outputs
- UL certification
- As small and light as possible

Unfortunately, this is literally the only charger I've found so far that fits those requirements. Frankly, it's still larger than I'd like, and their previous 165W charger didn't seem to have amazing reliability, but it's all I can find at the moment.

Comment: I am aware of this one, see my Reddit post: [New Satechi 145W is a bit disappointing](https://reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/195atme/new_satechi_145w_is_a_bit_disappointing): The new Satechi 145W is similar to the 165W: 4 USB C ports and a C7 input. It's laid out differently though and so it ships with a duckhead which clicks into place so by default it's a wall wart instead of a desktop charger.

Otherwise, it's not smaller or lighter weight.

The 165W is 3.93 x 1.22 x 2.8 inches, 12 oz, In metric that's 100mm x 71mm x 31mm , 340g.

The new 145W is 96mm x 76mm x 31mm , 346g.

Comment: Ah yeah, saw the post but didn't check the username lol. Saw you mentioned the 165W in this post but not the 145W. I'd agree, it's not ideal, but it's the best thing on the market currently (for me at least.)